# Desktop app using ADFS over WCF (claims auth), gives generic 'failed' code for issuedtokenmixedsymmetricbasic256

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, adfs2.0, adfs

There's a load of stuff to cover, so I'll try to keep it structured, as all good programmers should.. bear with me.

## My Environment

- .NET 3.5 SP1 Smart Client
- Uses WCF+SOAP over HTTP to communicate to server for business logic / data access
- Typically uses a custom (username+password) or Windows authentication scheme
- Current work aims to extend to include a new Claims-based authentication scheme to facilitate SSO with ADFS

## So far...

- Main service endpoints using ws2007FederationHttpBinding bindings, configuration set up with Message security via trust/13/issuedtokenmixedsymmetricbasic256 ADFS 2.0 endpoint
- Issuer endpoint configured with IssuedTokenOverTransport to HTTPS trust/13/usernamemixed ADFS 2.0 endpoint
- Service has federateServiceHostConfiguration service behaviour specified
- Created temporary certificate authority (CA) cert
- Created temporary certificate signed by CA
- Installed certificate (including private key) and made available to IIS app pool process account
- Updated service WCF config to use X509 certificate
- Client modified with new app’s own Client scheme/mode, programmatically sets up channel factory to ignore errors caused by temporary certificate and disables certificate revocation checks
- Username/password credentials are successfully added (via standard WCF ClientCredentials object) to SOAP envelope of token requests
- Token is successfully generated by usernamemixed endpoint and is returned to the client

## My problem

- Immediately following the token being issued, the subsequent call to issuedtokenmixedsymmetricbasic256 endpoint fails with generic error message that the security of the message could not be validated.  Inspection of the SOAP envelope result gives no information at all beyond a simple ‘failed’ result enumeration value
- Full tracing has been enabled on ADFS 2.0 server, but no events are logged at all in Event Log or event traces to further diagnose
- Unable to configure to work in a federated manner thus far; token is successfully issues over usernamemixed endpoint in the ‘test’ environment (the internal ADFS server rather than a remote one).  Use of the ‘live’ environment gives a simple unexplained 401 HTTP status code whether using usernamemixed with confirmed and valid credentials, or windowsmixed, when trying to obtain a token
- Generally: Resources from Microsoft or other sources are either very scarce, very specific to one situation, and in a couple of cases, completely wrong or misleading

## So ask a question already, doofus

Why does the call the issuedtokenmixedsymmetricbasic256 that WCF makes after getting the token fail?  How can I diagnose the result?  Other than what I've already done - enabling all trace flags in the service host config, checking the event log and event tracing data, what can I do?

Note, if you're about to suggest a link to a screencast/guide/blog/seemingly all-encompassing MSDN article, please stop.  I believe I have found them all, tried them all, and what I need at this point - if you can help me please - is an answer to the above question.  Not a general resource.

Comment: I got to questions to your question: 1) does the WCF try to impersonate? 2) Do you have the chance to move to .NET 4.0, which can make some things more easy.

Comment: Thanks - No impersonation is used, and yes it is an option to move to .NET 4.0

Comment: We had less struggle with .NET 4.0 and System.IdentityModel than with Microsoft.IdentityModel, since it integrates better into WCF.

Comment: Did you set any Delegation Authorization Rules on the RP? They might be nessecary (and they are ugly as far as i remember ;))

Comment: I really am grateful for the attention, but I really need an answer to my questions, rather than 'try .NET 4.0' (could take weeks).  I don't know what a Delegation Authorization Rule is, or how to set one up.

Comment: Well essentially a Delegation Authorization Rule allows an Server to act as a user by presenting the users token. Which might be nesseccary in your case since you send the token back to the server.
The user running the wcf service has to be allowed to do that with the user token. You can create that rule in the relying party claims (third page).